# Deactivating buttons in HTML without ruining layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a series of `<div>`'s with buttons in each one.

```
  <div class="project-display">
      <h4>Project 1 (date)</h4>
      <button type="submit" class="project-button">Github</button>
      <button type="submit" class="project-button">Live Site</button>
      <button type="submit" class="project-button" id="desc" >Show Description</button>
  </div>
```

Not every button needs to be active all the time though. For example, sometimes there will be no Live Site for the app I am presenting. I can't remove the Live Site button because then my div would be smaller than its surrounding divs:

[image]

My ideas are to either leave the button there and draw a black line through it, or gray the button out to indicate that it cannot be clicked. How can I indicate this button is inactive without messing up my layout?

Comment: `<button disabled="disabled">`?

Comment: Sweet, both those will do. I'll experiment with them. Thanks guys!

Comment: or, you could just remove the button and set the div to a fixed height

Comment: hmmm ruining usability to preserve layout doesn't seem the best plan to me - can't you use something like `display:table-cell` or a fixed height value to ensure the divs are the same height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not combine the HTML semantic state `disabled` with the visual style `line-through`, e.g:

```css
button:disabled {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<button disabled="true">DISABLED</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this 2 ways:

**Method 1:** Create a css style for all disabled buttons throughout the site

**In your site's css file:**

```
<style type="text/css">
   /* Style your disabled Buttons */
   button:disabled {
       background: white;
       border: 0;
       color: #666;
       cursor: pointer;
   }
</style>
```

**In your code on a certain scenario:**
Disable the necessary buttons using JavaScript.

**Method 2:** Create a css class that you can apply to individual buttons to make them appear disabled

**In your site's main css file:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* Style your disabled Buttons */
    .disabled-button {
       background: white;
       border: 0;
       color: #666;
       cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

**In your code on a certain scenario:**
Add the 'disabled-button' css class to the necessary buttons and disable the buttons using JavaScript.